# How to Hide an image stored in second TD based on the values of table stored in first TD with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 2 columns TABLE with first TD containing another TABLE with 3 rows of contents and second TD with an image as below:-

```
<table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    Wellness and Care
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    630 Woodbury Drive
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    641.613.1450
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    No Webaddress
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" id="imgPhone">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    Hospital
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    N/A
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    641.613.1451
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    No Webaddress
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" id="imgPhone">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am trying to disable the image on the second column of the row, if the Value of one of the TD is "N/A". I am stuck at getting the parent TR and going to second TD to do something.

My try is as follows:

```
$('#myTable tr').each(function () {

    if ($(this).find("td").text().trim() == "N/A") {
        var cellIndex = $(this).index();
        var nextTD = $(this).children('td').eq(1).index();
       // I am basically stuck here in getting next TD

    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: will you be able to add some class attribute values to the markup?

Comment: One more related question: How can I move all the table row which contain td with Text= 'N/A" to the top of the parent table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jD3hT/)

```
$('#myTable td:first-child td:contains("N/A")').parents('td').next().find('img').hide();
```

Comment: Simple and sweet solution. Worked like a charm. Please see one more related question to manipulate the table with the text "N/A"

Comment: @Ann are you looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jD3hT/1/ ? http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jD3hT/2/

Comment: Thanks! Prepend was what I was looking for. However, I didn't ask the question correctly. Actually, I got the answer thru' this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411373/how-to-move-table-to-the-top-of-the-div-container-based-on-a-condition-with-jque

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$( '#myTable td:first-child td:contains("N/A")' ).closest('tr').closest('td').next().find('img').hide()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dbGx3/)

Comment: Another simple and sweet solution. I liked it too. Please see one more related question to manipulate the table with the text "N/A"

Answer (score 1):

What I would do in your case is add a class for your 4 `tr` tags with text. Then you can just parse through each of those 4 by their class and if one of them is equal to 'N/A' you can grab the image by its ID and hide it.

HTML:

```
<td class="test" align="left">
    Wellness and Care
</td>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.test').each(function () {
    if($(this).text().trim() == 'N/A') {
        $("#imgPhone").toggle();
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ax6Mv/

Comment: This is a good solution too. I like the one liner ones so that it can be managed easily in the code. This works great too.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
$( '#myTable td:first td' ).each(
  function() {
    if ( $( this ).text().trim() == 'N/A' ) {
      $( '#myTable td' ).eq( 1 ).hide();
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This is a good start- but doesn't seem to work right out of the box. Since, I got some good working code- I am not taking time to evaluate this one.