# How to move table to the top of the DIV container based on a Condition with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple tables stacked inside a div container as below:-

```
<div id="myContent"  style="display: block;">
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      Health Care
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      20 Wisconsin Ave</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      641.235.5900
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      No website
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
              <table >
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">Housing</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      N/A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      641.255.3884
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      www.housingl.org
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="myTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      Employment</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">N/A</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      641.743.0500
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                      http://www.noexperience.org
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
              <img src="images/phone.png" class="imgHeader" >
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

I am trying to run a condition to find the TD with N/A and move those tables to the top. This is an additional question bult on the top of my previous question:

[Finding the text "N/A" and hiding an image in table's next TD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406537/how-to-hide-an-image-stored-in-second-td-based-on-the-values-of-table-stored-in)

I have a starting trouble with this code. Any support is appreciated.

Comment: Quick side note, all of your tables have the same `id`. You'll probably want to change their `id`s or switch them to `class`es.

Comment: Thanks for the note- somehow, those tables are created by a third party app and I have no control on it. So, thought of manipulating the data after it has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('td:contains(N/A)').closest('table').prependTo('#myContent');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jrag7/1/)**

Comment: Perfect one liner code -short and sweet. I have to pick this code as the answer due to the ease of manageability

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() === 'N/A') {
        $(this).parents('table').detach().prependTo('#myContent');
    }
});
```

Comment: Neil, I tried-but didn't have enough reputation to do that. Now, I could do that.-Sorry!